# Django: "Error importing request processor module" using custom processor

Tags: django

I've implemented my own context processor and I'm trying to configure it properly in django's settings:

```
from django.conf.global_settings import TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS as DEFAULT_PROCESSORS
MY_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    'django.core.context_processors.request',
    'com.mysite.apps.myapp.processors.MyProcessor.MyProcessor.process',
)
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = DEFAULT_PROCESSORS + MY_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS
```

but I got the following error:

> Error importing request processor module
>   com.mysite.apps.myapp.processors.MyProcessor.MyProcessor: "No module
>   named MyProcessor"

`MyProcessor` is a simple class with a static method "`process`" (I love OOP and I use classes and package architecture in my project). It exits and is spelled correctly... so what's wrong?

**UPDATE:**

by replacing my class with a simple "`process`" function ("`com.mysite.apps.myapp.processors.MyProcessor.process`") it works... but I'm not satisfied... how does Django load these processors? I use a packages/classes approach everywhere in my app (models, tests, views...) and it usually works... what's the difference here? Since the dynamic nature of Python, a path like "`com.mysite.apps.myapp.processors.MyProcessor.MyProcessor`" should be resolved independently from a class or a standard "submodule"... don't you agree?

Comment: What happens if you do `python manage.py shell` and try  `import com.mysite.apps.myapp.processors.MyProcessor.MyProcessor.process`? If that doesn't work, what about importing `com.mysite.apps.myapp.processors`?

Comment: Are you sure your directory structure has `MyProcessor` within `MyProcessor` ? That looks like the issue to me.

Comment: I just tried "from com.mysite.apps.myapp.processors.MyProcessor import MyProcessor" in the shell and it works... so it's right spelled and the file exists :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Django doesn't know whether `.` signifies a subpackage or a variable within that package.
So given `foo.bar.baz.quux` it assumes that `foo`, `bar`, `baz` are all packages, and that `quux` (i.e. the last value) is an attribute of that module.

`TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS` ultimately has its values imported by `django.template.context.get_standard_processors` ([source code](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.4.5/django/template/context.py#L137)).

This is the relevant bit of code in that function:

```
i = path.rfind('.')
module, attr = path[:i], path[i+1:]
```

So you can't access nested values within a module. This is not clearly documented anywhere that I can see. If you really want to access a static method, the only option I can see is:

```
class MyProcessor(object):

    @staticmethod
    def process(request):
        # whatever ...


process = MyProcessor.process
```

and then add to your `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS` `"com.mysite.apps.myapp.processors.MyProcessor.process"`

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a file called `MyProcessor.py`? It sounds like Python's expecting you to have:

```
com/mysite/processors/MyProcessor.py
```

Comment: Its expecting the py file within a folder of the same name

Comment: of course I have a module called MyProcessor containing a class called MyProcessor... I'm able to import that class in the shell!